# Changing markersize in geodataframeplot gives unexpected input error for plot(markersize=1)

Tags: matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I would like to plot similar data from separate (similar) using geodataframeplot. To improve the plot the markersize needs to be decreased for all points.

```
base=dbf['geometry'].plot(figsize = (10,10))
plt.tight_layout()

# Create user-defined bins
bins = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
ax2 = base
# Classify data with user-defined bins
q1 = mc.UserDefined(dbf1['column_1'], bins)
q2 = mc.UserDefined(dbf2['column_1'], bins)
q3 = mc.UserDefined(dbf3['column_1'], bins)
q4 = mc.UserDefined(dbf4['column_1'], bins)

# Plot data with user-difened bins
q1.plot(PS_Radarsat2, ax = ax2, legend = True, cmap="YlOrRd")
q2.plot(PS_Sentinel1_asc1, ax=ax2, legend = False, cmap = "YlOrRd")
q3.plot(PS_Sentinel1_asc2, ax=ax2, legend = False, cmap = "YlOrRd")
q4.plot(PS_Sentinel1_dsc1_IW1, ax=ax2, legend = False, cmap = "YlOrRd")
```

The code above works well, but unlike other instances, the plot(markersize=1) results in an unexpected input argument for .plot(). Is it possible to change the markersize while using a colormap argument?

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided data / MWE.  So used natural earth to simulate
- **markersize** does not apply to polygons, so it's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve with it
- clearly the *centroid* of a polygon in a point.  This can be plotted as a marker with a marker size on the figure.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mapclassify as mc
import numpy as np

# need to know countries that make up natural earth...
dbf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

base=dbf['geometry'].plot(figsize = (10,10))
plt.tight_layout()

dbf["column_1"] = np.random.uniform(0.4,1, len(dbf))
dbf1 = dbf.sample(10)
dbf2 = dbf.sample(10)
dbf3 = dbf.sample(10)
dbf4 = dbf.sample(10)
PS_Radarsat2 = dbf1
PS_Sentinel1_asc1 = dbf2
PS_Sentinel1_asc2 = dbf3
PS_Sentinel1_dsc1_IW1 = dbf4

# Create user-defined bins
bins = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
ax2 = base
# Classify data with user-defined bins
q1 = mc.UserDefined(dbf1['column_1'], bins)
q2 = mc.UserDefined(dbf2['column_1'], bins)
q3 = mc.UserDefined(dbf3['column_1'], bins)
q4 = mc.UserDefined(dbf4['column_1'], bins)

# # Plot data with user-difened bins
q1.plot(PS_Radarsat2, ax = ax2, legend = True, cmap="YlOrRd")
q2.plot(PS_Sentinel1_asc1, ax=ax2, legend = False, cmap = "YlOrRd")
q3.plot(PS_Sentinel1_asc2, ax=ax2, legend = False, cmap = "YlOrRd")
q4.plot(PS_Sentinel1_dsc1_IW1, ax=ax2, legend = False, cmap = "YlOrRd")

dbf1["geometry"].centroid.plot(ax=ax2, markersize=300, color="pink")
dbf2["geometry"].centroid.plot(ax=ax2, markersize=200, color="green")
dbf3["geometry"].centroid.plot(ax=ax2, markersize=100, color="yellow")
dbf4["geometry"].centroid.plot(ax=ax2, markersize=50, color="orange")
```

[image]